# I cant retrieve firebase data to my flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I cant load data from firebase to my flutter app. There shows an error. I don't know why its happening. Mainly I want to retrieve data from firebase. But when I run this code its not working. May be there are some problems in my code. I need the solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "xyz",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Firebase"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: FirstApp(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstApp> createState() => _FirstAppState();
}

class _FirstAppState extends State<FirstApp> {
  var firestoreDB =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("0xethocity").snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: firestoreDB,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
              return Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']);
            });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually Stream builder is a async task so you have to wait and check before trying to use the data. Try -

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: firestoreDB,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
       return Center(
         child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
       );
    }
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
          return Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']);
        }
    );
  },
);
```

Hope it helps.